# how to get the url running in xml using xsl?

Tags: html, xml, url, xslt, href

FoI have something like this in my xml file

```
    <tutor>
        <heading>tutor</heading>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph one two <a href="http://three.com">three</a> four give</p>
        <ul>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
        </ul>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph<a href="http://acho.com">test</a> one two two three</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
    </tutor>
```

how can I output the links correctly using xsl? I tried applying templates and using for-each but just couldn't do it correctly I have something like this in my xsl file

```
  <xsl:template match="tutor">
    <h4><xsl:value-of select="./heading" /></h4>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="./p" /></p>
    <a href="{./p/a/@href}"><xsl:value-of select="./p/a" /></a>
  </xsl:template>
```

but and something similar but just couldn't get it right.  Can someone please give me a hand?  Thanks

my output that I want is something like....

```
tutor
paragraph
paragraph one two three four give
the bullet lists and so on
```

and where three is will be a link just like how things are outputted in html

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current statement...

... is that this is only going to look for an `a` element in the first `p` element in the XML, which is not the case here.

If your XML already contains valid HTML elements, you can just use the [XSLT Identity Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to output them as they appear

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, you only need to write templates for the XML elements you do wish to change. For example, you don't want to output the `tutor` elements, so you can add a template to skip over it

```
<xsl:template match="tutor">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

And to change `heading` into `h4` you write a template like this

```
<xsl:template match="heading">
    <h4><xsl:apply-templates/></h4>
</xsl:template>
```

All other elements `p` and `a` and `ul` will be output as they are.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="tutor">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="heading">
        <h4><xsl:apply-templates/></h4>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: AH! Ok...totally understand that now....that's also what copy means? like of like `copy-of select=""` kind of thing?

Comment: `xsl:copy` just copies the node, but nothing else (i.e. no attributes or child nodes).

Comment: alright thanks a lot. been missing the obvious again :( Thought it's something complicated or need to do if statements or something like self node child node stuffs